# Does AREF pin of ATMEGA series consume any current?

Tags: atmega, voltage-reference

I have a voltage reference in the circuit and I thought I can feed that reference to AREF pin of ATMEGA as well:

[image]

The current at "1.024V" tag is around 200 uA, any current drawn by the AREF can affect the reference voltage to some degree.

- Does the AREF pin draw any current? how much?
- Can any noise on the AREF pin (or the MCU itself) affect the reference voltage?
- Can I dump that 10 uH inductor (LC filter) which is recommended and used in most designs at AREF pin?

Comment: What does the ATmega datasheet say?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It seems that it's not mentioned in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Microchip%208bit%20mcu%20AVR%20ATmega8A%20data%20sheet%20summary%2040001991A.pdf)!

Comment: @ElliotAlderson that was the summary datasheet my bad sorry, this is the full datasheet, [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega8A-Data-Sheet-DS40001974B.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opened datasheet, Ctrl+F, aref, 38 clicks down there is a wonderful picture!
As for two other questions:

2. Yes, of course, external reference should be really as smooth as possible.
3. Following from 2, depends on the precision you need (if you measure like 0.1 vs 0.4 V vs 0.8 V you probably don't care, but if you need 0.45 vs 0.5 precision, better keep the coil)

[image]

Comment: P.S. I checked Atmega328p 3 clicks down, it's exactly the same!

Comment: Mine is Atmega8A but has the same graph, thanks. there's 2 questions left to answer though.

Comment: added answers, sry, totally forgot about them when opened datasheet...:D